# R - How can we delete rows based on logical argument between two columns value

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, row

I wanted to know how I could delete the rows where the values in two different columns is not the same. Here is an example to illustrate my problem:

```
test.1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
test.2 <- c("2009-02", "2009-04", "2010-01", "2011-02")
test.3 <- c("2009-02", "2009-08", "2010-01", "2013-06")
test.data <- data.frame(test.1, test.2, test.3)
```

which gives:

```
test.1  test.2  test.3
1      A 2009-02 2009-02
2      B 2009-04 2009-08
3      C 2010-01 2010-01
4      D 2011-02 2013-06
```

I would like to delete the rows where test.2 & test.3 are not equal, i.e. the second and fourth rows. I tried with the function duplicated as I found that

```
test.data.2 = test.data[!duplicated(test.data[,c('test.2', 'test.3')]),]
```

would remove the rows where test.2 = test.3. Therefore, I remove "!" as followed:

```
test.data.2 = test.data[duplicated(test.data[,c('test.2', 'test.3')]),]
```

but it is not working. Would you have any other suggestions?
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

test.data %>%
  filter(test.2 == test.3)
```

Or base R:

```
test.data[test.data$test.2 == test.data$test.3,]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `subset` to subset the rows from `base R`

```
subset(test.data, test.2 == test.3)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test.data %>%
      slice(which(test.2 == test.3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new dataframe where only the values where `test.2` and `test.3` are the same:

```
test.data.2 <- test.data[test.data$test.2 == test.data$test.3,]
```

Likewise, you can filter out values where they are not the same:

```
test.data.2 <- test.data[-which(test.data$test.2 != test.data$test.3),]
```